# What is the best way to store large data when training a model?

Tags: dataset

This is rather a technical question, when training the model I import data locally to `Google Colab runtime` which does not seem to be efficient, when the runtime disconnects, the data is lost.

Is there a better way to store the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data in Google Drive and mount it from your Colab notebook (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52300696) for detailed instructions).